# iOS 7 force landscape on a UIViewController with UINavigationController

Tags: xcode, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

In my app I want one view controller to be shown in landscape because it is a signature pad.  The rest of the views are portrait.  I can force the view to be landscape without a problem as long as it is not embedded in a Navigation Controller.  The problem is that I want the Navigation bar to show also.  Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either `present` your view controller instead of `push` using `UINavigationController` (See kjam's solution in the following link) or you may try [this solution of arpan_techisavy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987249/how-do-i-programmatically-set-device-orientation-in-ios7).

Comment: I'll try that solution.  Thanks.  I was hoping to find a more accepted or "official" way of doing this.

Comment: @BrianKalski, AFAIK, the solutions i have suggested are the official solutions. One using the standard key-value pair and other one using public APIs.