# How to segue from landscape to portrait orientated view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation

I'm working on an app that works only in landscape orientation but there's an option to access the photo roll and choose pictures to be used in the app.

This works only in portrait mode.

So I have have to work with 2 view controllers, one that needs to be in portrait mode only and the second that should always be in landscape mode. Does anyone knows how I can accomplish this in Swift?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work ?

Comment: Try this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20987296/2497120