# Xcode Deployment Info and icons using CMake

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

I've tried looking for info on how to set these (in red) using CMake but have had no luck so far:

[image]

**1st red box issue:**

First of all, even though the device seems like it's been set to 'Universal' correctly, the value isn't being interpreted correctly by Xcode. When I set it to 'Universal' manually using the dropdown, it gives a tab each for iPhone and iPad. Furthermore, I know it's not being interpreted correctly as the app does not function correctly (in my case, neither the launch image nor the app itself run full screen).

I don't think setting orientation programmatically is an option for me since I need the launch image in the correct orientation as well.
So can't do something like this:
[How do I programmatically set device orientation in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987249/how-do-i-programmatically-set-device-orientation-in-ios7)

**2nd red box issue:**

I use an asset file for all my icons, so at the moment I'm having to build using CMake and then press 'Use Asset Catalog' each time.
I found this but doesn't seem very useful:
http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Icon-and-Launch-image-support-for-iOS-apps-td7590970.html

Comment: Might be helpful: You can set any xcode option via e.g.  set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iOS Developer") - that means if you can find the option name in your ios project (should be easy to diff) - then you can easily set it via XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_XXX.

Comment: @MartinGerhardy The thing is, for the orientation configuration, it's not an `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_<...>`, it's configured in the plist file.

Comment: What if you use configure_file on a MyApp.plist.in and set the proper cmake vars that should be replaced?

Comment: To ensure the device family is being set to Universal correctly, you can add this cmake setting: `set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY "1,2")`

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the "1st box issue", I've found that the approach taken by this demo project works really well.

https://github.com/forexample/testapp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

They use a templated `Info.plist` to inject the bundle identifier, etc, during configure. The nice part is then you can modify the orientations in the `plist.in` file, and then these get translated cleanly to the `Info.plist` once you open the project.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 2nd red box issue, i found that the attribute I needed to set was `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME`

For example:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME "AppIcon")
```

For Launch Images I got it to work by setting it in the plist.in file under UILaunchStoryboardName as described in yano's previous answer.