# lock orientation of a viewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, locking, orientation, viewcontroller

I'm a newbie in Swift and i have a problem locking the orientation to portrait in a viewController. Actually i have locked it using this code in my Custom Navigation Controller

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if (self.visibleViewController is ViewController)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
    return .All
}
```

Everything works fine and the ViewController is locked to portrait.The problem is when return to this controller from another in landscape mode.
if i return to ViewController (pressing back from the NextViewController) in landscape then the ViewController appeared in landscape. Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20987296/1959140
In view did apprear, change the orientation.

Answer (score 8):

In swift 3 this solution works

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is LockedViewController {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
}
```

Change `LockedViewController` to match the controller you would like locked.

Comment: Wow. This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for posting this!!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the methods below

```
 override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
  }
  override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
  }
```

Then, in your viewDidLoad, force the orientation by adding the code below

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: thank's for your reply. The missing code was UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation") but it works better on viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

For swift3.0

To restrict different orientations for different views You need to do following things :

In App delegate File :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is OtherViewController {

            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;

        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does this not work in Swift 4? Can't get it too work.