# ios set screen rotate whether the device locked or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie

When my device is locked, but in my app, I want to tap a button, my app(view controller) will rotate. Just like my device is not locked and has already set orientationMaskAll, then I rotate my device, the view controller rotate?

I want to make a custom movie player. when MPMoviePlayerController view addsubview in a containView, when I tap a button, the device rotate, and the MPMoviePlayerController view enter fullscreen!

Comment: @Nitin do you know how to do? It seems force rotate.

Comment: I am just looking to this. please check this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041650/ios7-ios6-conditional-rotation-portrait-landscape-for-different-sections-of. I will update you if i got anything.

Comment: Thank you first of all! I have already check this link, but it is not i need. Thanks!

Comment: @alexshafran the question of "force the interface from portrait to landscape orientation while the device remains in portrait orientation", have you already solved?

Comment: not yet!!![link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125263/force-device-rotation-with-attemptrotationtodeviceorientation-failing)

Comment: @Nitin the question of that link now is what i need. But the accepted just tell the reason, didn't give answer.

Comment: @Nitin i think i have got it. When i call attmptRotationToDeviceOrientation, then shouldAutorotate return yes and then supportedInterfaceOrientations return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait. actrually, the screen is rotate,  but because the shouldAutorotate is return yes, and the screen is landscape so the viewcontroller will rotate(call shouldAutorotate second),so if the second time i return no.the viewcontroller will not rotate. It will stay portrait.